# Kivy global ID list

Tags: python, kivy

I was trying to implement a method in python to register every ID of my TextInputs.

I am new to kivy and there are multiple things that I do not quiet understand.
My test code is the following:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


class KivyGuiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

    ''' interface for  global widget access '''
    global_widgets = {}

    def register_widget(self, widget_object):
        print(widget_object.gid)

    def print_widgets(self):
        for w in self.global_widgets:
            print(w)



class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    pass


root_widget = Builder.load_string("""
MyBox:
    gid: "4"
    on_pos: app.register_widget(self)
    name: 'screen_manager'
    SimpleLayout:

<SimpleLayout@BoxLayout>:
    gid: "1"
    on_pos: app.register_widget(self)
    name: 'simple_layout_rule'

    TextInput:
        gid: "inputB"
        on_pos: app.register_widget(self)

    TextInput:
        gid: "inputC"
        on_pos: app.register_widget(self)

    TextInput:
        gid: "inputD"
        on_pos: app.register_widget(self)

    """)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    KivyGuiApp().run()
```

The output of that code is going to be:

```
inputC
inputD
1
inputC
inputD
```

Questions:

1. Why does it skip the gid "4" of MyBox
2. Why can I simply create the variable "gid" for each widget?
3. Why does it skip the gid "inputB". This will also happen for inputC if I would remove the first TextInput (so always the first one will not be displayed)

I would very happy if someone could help me understand why kivy is doing this.

Greetings,
Finn

Comment: The `on_pos` only activates when the widgets `pos` property changes. Since the default `pos` is `(0,0)`, any widget that doesn't need to change that position, will not fire the `on_pos` event. You  might consider using the `Window` event `on_show` and traverse the widgets with a top widget's `walk` method.

Comment: Well I tried that but it keeps telling me:

 >>   37:    on_show: print("aiwdj")
      38:
      39:<ParameterFileInput>
 ...
 AttributeError: show

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why does it skip the gid "4" of MyBox

You are calling the `register_widget()` function every time the position changes, in addition the default position of any widget is the position `(0, 0)`, and in the case of `MyBox`, which is the root, it never changes position, so register_widget never is called.

> 2. Why can I simply create the variable "gid" for each widget?

In the [`Kivy language`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file) the creation of `properties` uses that syntax, in your case you are creating a [`StringProperty`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty).

> 3. Why does it skip the gid "inputB". This will also happen for inputC if I would remove the first TextInput (so always the first one will not be displayed)

The first one will not be shown because the position of the first widget within a layout has the position `(0, 0)` so the `BoxLayout` does not change its position and consequently `on_pos` is never triggered.

kivy does not change the position of a widget if it is not necessary, the change of position implies repainting, by not doing so we save the execution of that task.

---

To verify what I'm saying, let's change the position of `MyBox` with the help of a `Clock`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        BoxLayout.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.on_change, 1)

    def on_change(self, *args):
        print("=====================")
        print("change position")
        print("=====================")
        self.pos = (100, 100)


root_widget = Builder.load_string("""
MyBox:
    gid: "4"
    on_pos: app.register_widget(self)
    name: 'screen_manager'
    SimpleLayout:

<SimpleLayout@BoxLayout>:
    gid: "1"
    on_pos: app.register_widget(self)
    name: 'simple_layout_rule'

    TextInput:
        gid: "inputB"
        on_pos: app.register_widget(self)

    TextInput:
        gid: "inputC"
        on_pos: app.register_widget(self)

    TextInput:
        gid: "inputD"
        on_pos: app.register_widget(self)

    """)

class KivyGuiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

    def register_widget(self, widget_object):
        print(widget_object.gid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    KivyGuiApp().run()
```

The following output is obtained:

```
inputC
inputD
1
inputC
inputD
=====================
change position
=====================
4
1
inputB
inputC
inputD
```

Of the impression it is observed that when the position of the root is changed all the widgets are changed of position.

Comment: perfect!! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @FinnEggers 
what happened? What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Oh. Nothing. It was perfect. I think I missclicked

Answer (score 2):

I tried using the `on_show` event, but was not successful, so I used the `on_draw` event instead. Here is your code with the `on_pos` references removed and the `on_draw` implemented:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


class KivyGuiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

    ''' interface for  global widget access '''
    global_widgets = {}

    def register_widget(self, widget_object):
        print(widget_object.gid)

    def print_widgets(self):
        for w in self.global_widgets:
            print(w)



class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    pass

root_widget = Builder.load_string("""
MyBox:
    gid: "4"
    name: 'screen_manager'
    SimpleLayout:

<SimpleLayout@BoxLayout>:
    gid: "1"
    name: 'simple_layout_rule'

    TextInput:
        gid: "inputB"

    TextInput:
        gid: "inputC"

    TextInput:
        gid: "inputD"

    """)

def on_draw(*args):
    app = App.get_running_app()
    for widget in root_widget.walk():
        app.register_widget(widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.bind(on_draw=on_draw)
    KivyGuiApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!:) that helped me a lot